# How to call a stored proc in db2 database from spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to call a stored proc in db2 that takes 3 arguments and return an integer . Can anyone help me to call this sp from spark Scala code.
Below is the stored proc in db2.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(IN V_DATE DATE,IN V_GROUP VARCHAR(20),IN V_FREQ 
VARCHAR(20),IN V_RULE VARCHAR(20), OUT ID INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
LOCK TABLE CAL_LOG IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
SET ID = (10+ COALESENCE((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CAL_LOG WITH UR),0));
INSERT INTO CAL_RESULT(ID,P_DATE,GROUP,FREQ,RULE)
VALUES(ID,V-DATE,V_GROUP,V_FREQ,V_RULE);
COMMIT:
END;
```

PROC is created and it is working as expected.

Now i want to call this proc from spark scala code.
I am trying the below code

```
val result = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.options(Map(
"url"-> //the db2 url
"driver" - > // my db2 driver
"user name" - > // username
"password" -> // password
""dbtable" -> "(CALL TEST_PROC('2020-07-08','TEST',''TEST','TEST,?)) as proc_result;"
)).load()
```

but the code snippet is giving below error

```
DB@ SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: Not possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JDBC connection directly instead of Spark, as your stored procedure only returns an integer. If you need that value you can retrieve that from the call to the stored procedure, but using Scala without using Spark.

You can find a sample at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvcscsp.html

That's the standard way to call it on any language:

- If you need to replace parameters, you can use the prepareCall as described on the link above
- assign the parameters values with the registerParameter (In or Out)
- run the executeQuery as your sp returns an integer
- close the connection

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [ScalikeJDBC](http://scalikejdbc.org/)

Maven coordinates (Scala 2.11): `org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc_2.11:3.4.1`

```
import scalikejdbc._

// Initialize JDBC driver & connection pool
Class.forName(<db2 driver>)
ConnectionPool.singleton(<url>, <user>, <password>)

// ad-hoc session provider on the REPL
implicit val session = AutoSession 

// Now you can run anything you want
sql"""
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(IN V_DATE DATE,IN V_GROUP VARCHAR(20),IN V_FREQ 
VARCHAR(20),IN V_RULE VARCHAR(20), OUT ID INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
LOCK TABLE CAL_LOG IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
SET ID = (10+ COALESENCE((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CAL_LOG WITH UR),0));
INSERT INTO CAL_RESULT(ID,P_DATE,GROUP,FREQ,RULE)
VALUES(ID,V-DATE,V_GROUP,V_FREQ,V_RULE);
COMMIT:
END;""".execute.apply()
```

Fetch data as follows

```
sql"""(CALL TEST_PROC('2020-07-08','TEST',''TEST','TEST,?)) 
as proc_result;""".execute.apply()
```

The result can be turned into a dataframe again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call stored procedure using Apache Spark though load same data using Spark load

Load fron db2

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val df= sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
                       "url" -> "jdbc:db2://xx.xx.xx.xx:50000/SQLDB:securityMechanism=9;currentSchema=vaquarkhan;user=<ur-username>;password=xxxxx;",
        "driver" -> "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",
        "dbtable" -> "scheam.TableName"))
```

Create temp table/df and add filters to get required response.